# Kivy label visual glitch when switching screens

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making a simple basic facts maths app in Kivy. I'm using ScreenManager to switch between different screens. When I switch between my screen, I'm getting an annoying visual glitch with my labels at the top of each page.

[image]

I've tried setting IDs to each label but that didn't do anything, I'm pretty new to kivy so have no idea what I'm doing.

The Program is in 2 files:
main.kv

```
Manager:
    MainMenu:
    GameMode:
    DifficultyScreen:
    Game:
<MainMenu>:
    name: "menu"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 2

        Label:
            text: "More On Maths"
            id: home_title
        Button:
            text: "Play"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "gamemode_screen"
<GameMode>:
    name: "gamemode_screen"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 5

        Label:
            text: "Select Game Mode"
            id: gamemode_select
        Button:
            text: "Addition"
            on_press: root.btn_add()
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "difficulty_screen"
```

main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainMenu(Screen):
    pass
class GameMode(Screen):
    pass
class DifficultyScreen(Screen):
    pass
class Game(Screen):
    pass
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

Anyone encountered this before? Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Non-ideal fix: I changed my transition type to FadeTransition(). It seems this bug is to do with animation, so it works fine when I don't use the default SlideTransition.

Comment: Hi, please show your entire code, I've got this feeling its the labeling issue under the "gamemode-screen".

Comment: I've discovered this seems to be an issue with my computer/os, as when I ran my program on my Ubuntu partition everything was fine.